# Hidekazu Yukawa in Shenmue?

Tags: shenmue

The former Senior Managing Director of Sega, Hidekazu Yukawa (aka. "Mr. SEGA") appears in *What‘s Shenmue?*.

I heard that he also appears in *Shenmue* (apart from his face on the battery boxes in the Tomato Convenience Store).

Is this true? How and where can you meet him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two situations where you can meet Hidekazu Yukawa in *Shenmue*.

You need the two toys **Mr. Yukawa Happi** and **Mr. Yukawa Suit**.

You can win them at the raffle (2nd and 3rd prize) in the Abe Store in Sakuragaoka. ([This gameplay video (0:00 to 0:50)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6F5zE8sb5rE) shows how Ryo wins these two figures.)

#### Takara Sushi

On the 9th of any month, between 8-9 pm, visit Takara Sushi in Dobuita. You’ll see Mr. Yukawa standing behind the bar.

In the Japanese version, you can speak with him, after which he’ll run away:

Ryo says something like "You are Mr. Yukawa, aren’t you?", and Yukawa answers "Impossible!" and runs away.

In this version (I’m not sure if it’s the EU/NA version or if it’s the JP "US Shenmue") there is no dialogue:

If you leave and reenter the sushi bar, he will be standing there again.

#### Bar Yokosuka

(Maybe this only works in the Japanese versions.)

On the day after Nozomi tells Ryo how she feels about him, visit Bar Yokosuka in Dobuita (which triggers the cutscene where Ryo is told that friends are waiting for him at his home).
If you visit the bar **after 11 pm**, you’ll see Mr. Yukawa having a drink in this cutscene.

You can see him in this video (from 0:17 on):

---

Sources:

- Thread in the Shenmue Dojo: [Say Hello to Mr. Yukawa at Takara Sushi!!](http://www.shenmuedojo.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10755)
- Shenmua Wikia: [Hidekazu Yukawa](http://shenmue.wikia.com/wiki/Hidekazu_Yukawa#Shenmue)
- Shenmue Neoseeker Wiki: [Takara Sushi](http://shenmue.neoseeker.com/wiki/Takara_Sushi)